# PHP missing cURL and XDebug after upgrade

Tags: debian, php, curl

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and went to check on my local apache2 installation by adding phpinfo() to an index file.

I do not see an entry for cURL or for XDebug.

Here's what I did:

1. Again, I checked phpinfo() and no curl or xdebug options are shown.
2. I went to /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini and uncommented the following line extension=php_curl.dll.
3. I then restarted apache.
4. Also, my phpinfo() shows Loaded Configuration File
   /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini and THAT is the one I've been editing.

However, WordPress still reports the following: PHP Fatal error: 
Call to undefined function curl_init().

I'm thinking I MUST be editing the wrong ini file.

Any ideas? I'm dead in the water here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, if you are not finding the curl and/or xdebug extension/modules after an upgrade of the OS, you have to reinstall them.

In Debian compatible distributions such as Ubuntu the commands are:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl php-xdebug
```

After installing those PHP modules, restart Apache.

> Package: php7.1-curl
>
> CURL module for PHP [default]
>
> This package provides the CURL module for PHP.

Xdebug:

> Package: php-xdebug
>
> Xdebug Module for PHP
>
> The Xdebug extension helps you debugging your script by providing a lot of valuable debug information. The debug information that Xdebug can provide includes the following:
>
> - stack traces and function traces in error messages with:
>
>   - full parameter display for user defined functions
>   - function name, file name and line indications
>   - support for member functions
> - memory allocation
> - protection for infinite recursions
>
> Xdebug also provides:
>
> - profiling information for PHP scripts
> - script execution analysis
> - capabilities to debug your scripts interactively with a debug client

As for your edit, `php_curl.dll` is for Microsoft Windows and not Linux; please comment that again.

Comment: Greetings, I ran the above commands and now I see xdebug, but sadly still no curl. 
I DID run the following command "ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*" which gave the following results: ""/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.1.conf  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.1.load"

Comment: Try `apt-get install php7.0-curl` instead

Comment: I'm running 7.1 so I ran apt-get install php7.1-curl, restarted and WHALLA! Back in business (...I hope). Thanks! Please move your comment to an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks again to ALL posters.

Comment: Done, answer updated.